# Service Method called 5 times from Angular Controller

Tags: angularjs

This one has me confounded. I have looked far and wide and am out of ideas. In my searching, I discovered that one of the common reasons for multiple function calls on load is if you have a controller defined in routes and via the ngController directive. Checked this - I do not use ngController. I also checked my routes - seem in order. There are no $watch functions that could be causing $digest issues. This function is called one time, at the bottom of the function, and the console.log is logged out 5x...EVERY TIME. I have even set a $timer function and it still calls it 5x. Have tried creating a variable to only run if it hasn't been run before but it seems like it's all happening with the getQuotas() method. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
function getQuotas () 
{
    console.log('getQuotas'); //This logs out 5x

    UserService.getQuotas()
    .then(function(res)
    {
        if (res.data.success)
        {
            quotaData = res.data.data;
            getQuotas_success();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            getQuotas_failure();
            return false;
        }
    }, function (err)
    {
        getQuotas_failure();
        return false;
    });

}
getQuotas(); //Function is called here.
```

Comment: To how many different views you have assigned that controller? Do you have any `$state.reload()`?

Comment: Only one view. Sorry should have specified that. Could controller length/complexity have anything to do with it? I know best practices dictate that smaller controllers are better. This one is about 300 lines and has 3 different API calls as an FYI.

Comment: And I should point out that the other API calls seem to get called 5 times as well.

Comment: Not, it isn't cause by controller complexity at all. Based on my experience, such thing occurs if a controller is bound to many views via `ng-controller` or via `ngRoute`. It may be because, for some reason, you are calling you function more than once inside this controller.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! I'm hopeful this will help others. There was a custom attribute directive on each of 4 input fields on this page. That particular directive was using the same controller as the page itself. So the controller was getting loaded a total of 5 times. Fortunately for me, this directive is now deprecated but I would probably redo it by either creating a directive-level controller and using the 'require' attribute in the directive's return object, pointing to the page-level controller, OR just have the data that needs to get passed between the page-level controller and the directive go through a service.